# asp.net mvc telerik chart issue

Tags: telerik

I believe I have registred telerik properly.

This:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Menu()
        .Name("Menu")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("Item 11");
            items.Add().Text("Item 2");
        })
%>
```

shows a menu.

However, this:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Chart()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title(title => title
            .Text("Representative Sales vs. Total Sales")
        )
        .Series(series => {
            series.Bar(new int[] { 2015, 6003, 6881 }).Name("Representative Sales");
            series.Bar(new int[] { 15458, 26598, 27623 }).Name("Total Sales");
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .Categories(new string[] { "Aug 2010", "Sept 2010", "Oct 2010" })
        )
%>
```

shows nothing (code on the same page). I really do not know why. Any ideas? Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I copied and pasted what you have into a view. Both the menu and chart display correctly.  Maybe you are missing some js or css file. Try using the developer tools in your browser to see if something is missing.
[image]

Edit:
Point 4 in the [Telerik docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html) says, "The ScriptRegistrar should be placed after all components on the page. Typically you could put the ScriptRegistrar component at the end of the master page."
ScriptRegistrar declaration in Site.Master

```
    <!-- other content -->
    <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I switched firebug on (in firefox) and added: <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.DefaultPath("~/Scripts/2011.3.1115").Add("telerik.chart.min.js").Add("telerik.common.min.js"))%>
     
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/autocomplete.js") %>"></script>
    <%= Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
        .DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css")
                                     .Add("telerik.web20.min.css"))
        %>

Comment: I getting an error: b is undefined

(function(a,bz){var ab=document,b=a.te...ype.options.theme="default"})(jQuery); in telerik.chart.min.js

Comment: Be sure to place the Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistar() code at the bottom of your page or the master page. Telerik's documentation says, "The ScriptRegistrar should be placed after all components on the page. Typically you could put the ScriptRegistrar component at the end of the master page." http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I needed to do. I moved it up as telerik interfered with my other jquery plugins

Comment: I had a problem that when I used two charts. its shows only one thing